# How to filter subtotals in a pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'SalesOrderNumber':['SO1001','SO1001','SO1001','SO1002','SO1002'],
'SalesOrderLineNumber':[1,2,3,1,2],
'UnitPrice':[2000,800,1200,200,800]})
```

Below is a pivot table that I created from a dataframe:

```
table=pd.pivot_table(df,values=['UnitPrice'],index=['SalesOrderNumber'],columns=['SalesOrderLineNumber'],aggfunc=sum,margins=True,margins_name='Total')

table= table.stack('SalesOrderLineNumber')

print(table)
```

Here's the result of the table:

```
SalesOrderNumber SalesOrderLineNumber UnitPrice

 SO1001          1                     2000.00
                 2                      800.00
                 3                     1200.00
                 Total                 4000.00
 SO1002          1                      200.00
                 2                      800.00
                 Total                 1000.00
 Total           1                     2200.00
                 2                     1600.00
                 3                     1200.00
                 Total                 5000.00
```

How do I filter and show only subtotals that are 4000 or more? Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please include example data.